# C++ Opening a binary file

Tags: c++, file, binary

I want to open a binary file in C++.
but I have this function in C:

```
uint openPacket(const char* filename, unsigned char** buffer) {
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp) {
        size_t result;
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fsize = ftell(fp);
        rewind(fp);
        *buffer = new unsigned char[fsize];
        result = fread(*buffer, 1, fsize, fp);
        if (result != fsize) {
            printf("Reading error in %s, unable to send packet!\n", filename);
            delete[] * buffer;
            fsize = 0;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return fsize;
    } else {
        printf("Couldn't open %s for packet reading, unable to send packet!\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want to make something like: string OpenPacket(string filename)
but don't work :(

Comment: What doesn’t work? Show your code.

Comment: I understand you want to wrap the given function, and make a new one with a signature more like C#/Java's

 string OpenPacket(string filename)?

Comment: that cannot be "a function in C" unless C has suddenly acquired new[] and delete[].

Comment: Please Let us know the real problem in your code. `Dont work` statement did't tell any thing about your problem.

Comment: He is opening in binary mode. By the way you can use fstat to get the size of the file rather than seeking to the end and the start again.

Comment: not sure why you are mixing C and C++, instead of FILE* use fstream to read from file.

Comment: You haven't udestrood I want to trasnform that C function in a C++ function using ifstream, but I don't find a equals fuction to this, in my C function the result it's put in buffer)
instead I want to make a C++ function like:
string openPacket(string filename){
 ifstream file( filename, ios::in | ios::binary );
 if( ! file.is_open() ) return "";
 
 // read all file and return the result <- I can't do that
}

Comment: Won't work I need to use vector<char>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You Need this:

```
    uint openPacket(const char* filename, unsigned char** buffer) {
    ifstream file (filename, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    streampos size;
   if (file.is_open())
      {
        size = file.tellg();
        *buffer = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, size);
        file.close();

        cout << "the entire file content is in memory";
        return size;    
      }
```

For reference [Check this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

May be this is a possible wrapper function:

```
std::string openPacket( const std::string& filename )
{
    unsigned char* buff;
    uint size = openPacket( filename.c_str(), &buff );
    if( size )
    {
        std::string s( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buff), size );
        delete [] buff;
        return s;
    }
    return std::string();
}
```